# Kotlin - How to split the string into digits and string?

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, split

I want to split a long string (containing digits and characters) into different substrings in Kotlin?

eg:- Buy these 2 products and get 100 off

output needed -> "Buy these ","2 ","products and get ","100 ","off"

Comment: This looks like a line from a CSV file. If so, it's usually better to use an existing library to parse it — not only do you not have to muck around with regexes or whatever, but the library will cope with nested quotes, escape characters, comments, locale-specific separators, and all the other variations and corner cases and complications that you haven't thought of. (For example, [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) is free and open-source.)

Comment: I prefer to use answer by @Sam

Comment: also the answer by @Alireza Mahfouzian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression that will match either a group of digits, or a group of non-digit characters.

I used `\d+|\D+`.

- `\d+` will match groups of digits, like `2` and `100`
- `\D+` will match any sequence of characters that doesn't contain digits
- The `|` indicates that the pattern should match *either* `\d+` *or* `\D+`

Use [`findAll`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find-all.html) to find each part of the string that matches the pattern.

```kotlin
val regex = Regex("""\d+|\D+""")
val input = "Buy these 2 products and get 100 off"
val result = regex.findAll(input).map { it.groupValues.first() }.toList()
```

The result I get is:

```
["Buy these ", "2", " products and get ", "100", " off"]
```

The spacing isn't quite the same as what you're looking for, so you could trim the results, or adjust the regex pattern.

Answer (score 2):

this code also works well in this example:

```
val str = "Buy these 2 products and get 100 off"
val result = str.split(regex = Regex("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"))
```